# Does a fully faithful functor apply to identity arrows?

Tags: category-theory, functors, hom-functor

In Saunders Mac Lane's *Categories for the working mathematician* one can read, when talking about fully faithful functors:

> [...], but this need not mean that the functor itself is an isomorphism 
>   of categories, for there may be objects of B not in the image of T

Given a fully faithful functor $T: C \to B$ and an object together with its identity arrow $c \in C, 1_c: c \to c$, and given $T 1_c = 1_{Tc}: T c \to T c$ in $B$, how can there be a fully faithful functor between categories with unequal amounts of elements?

Because faithful functors follow the rule $Tf_1 = Tf_2 \Rightarrow f_1 = f_2$ and with categories with unequal (or rather *less*) elements there must be some $1_{Tc}$ that is equal to some $1_{Tc'}$

For me it seems to be the same reason why there is no injective function $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$

Comment: For **any** functor $T1_c=1_{Tc}$.

Comment: Functors map identity morphisms to identity morphisms by definition.

Comment: Further to the above comments, here's a silly class of examples of full and faithful functors between categories with unequal numbers of objects. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any [indiscrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category), i.e. a set of objects such that between any two objects there is exactly one morphism, and let $\mathbf{1}$ be the [terminal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/terminal+category), i.e. the category with one object and one (identity) morphism. The unique functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{1}$ is full and faithful.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Really? A faithful functor implies $Tf_1 = Tf_2 \Rightarrow f_1 = f_2$, but if $\forall f \in \mathcal{C}. T f = id_1$, (where $id_1$ is the single arrow in the terminal category) then this doesn't hold.

Comment: Because $Tf_1= Tf_2 \implies f_1=f_2$ need not hold, even if $T$ is faithful. For it to hold, you have to assume first that $f_1, f_2$ have the same domain and codomain: a faithful functor is injective when restricted to $Hom(A,B)$, not when restricted to $Mor(C)$

Comment: @hgiesel: Another (equivalent) perspective on what Max said: each functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ induces functions $F_{A,B} : \mathcal{C}(A,B) \to \mathcal{D}(FA,FB)$ for all $A,B \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C})$. To say that $F$ is faithful (resp. full) is to say that each of these functions is injective (resp. surjective). But this doesn't make $F$ injective (resp. surjective) on morphisms globally.

Comment: In the example you give in the last line, I assume you mean there's no *order preserving* injective function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$, but the function that maps $0$ and all negative numbers to $0$, and all positive numbers to themselves, *is a full and faithful functor between posets*. Neither full nor faithful care about how the *objects* of the category are mapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal C$ be *any* full subcategory of a category $\mathcal D$.  Then the inclusion $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal D$ gives a functor $F\colon\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$.  This functor is always fully faithfull, but it is not always true that a subcategory is isomorphic to the larger category.

For a really down to earth example take the category whose only object is the zero set with its identity map.  This includes into the category of all sets and these categories are not isomorphic.